# Error in making HTTP request from Frontend to Backend

Tags: express, cors, request-headers, preflight

I have facing an issue while making a HTTP POST request call from my frontend running on port 3000 to express server running on 4000. I am using mongoDB and making call to store my form data. When I checked the newtork tab of the console I saw CORS error so I applied cors middleware, but even then some error occures stating issues with prefilght request. I applied the preflight configs also but still I am unable to make call on my backed API route.I looked online it says to apply some header to the preflight request but I am not able to do it. Please help

[The network tab showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXfwj.png)

```
const savedResponse = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:4000/api/createuser`,
        {
          method:"POST",
          headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({...data})
        }
```

```
// Configure the cors options with preflight handling
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  
  
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], // Add other methods you need to support
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Access-Control-Allow-Headers"], // Add other custom headers you need to support
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // Some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};

// Apply the cors middleware with the specified options
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Can you show your Express code for ‘/api/createuser’ ?

Comment: Thank you for the response I got the solution by adding "origin":"*" in the header.